Nginx, Docker Certbot / Letsencrypt results in 404 for .well-known/acme-challenge/
Issue:
I'm setting up my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-36-generic x86_64) server to handle my Django site. We're going to run everything in a docker environment.
docker-compose up --build
Everything builds with no error messages but the issue comes with
 /.well-known/acme-challenge/
 /.well-known/acme-challenge/test-file/

Error messages for acme-challenge:
nginx_1    | 123.45.67.89 - - [06/Aug/2024:11:06:34 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/ HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1    | 2024/08/06 10:20:00 [error] 29#29: *12 "/var/www/allhoa/certbot/.well-known/acme-challenge/test-file/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 123.45.67.891, server: mydjangosite.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/test-file/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mydjangosite.com"
nginx_1    | 123.45.67.891 - - [06/Aug/2024:10:20:00 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/test-file/ HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1    | 123.45.67.891 - - [06/Aug/2024:10:20:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 27800 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
web_1      | 172.18.0.6 - - [06/Aug/2024:10:20:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 27800 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Ideal Outcome:
Successfully set up HTTPS via letsencrypt and certbot with auto renew
Relevant code:
file: /var/www/mydjangosite/config/gunicorn.conf.py
import multiprocessing

bind = "0.0.0.0:9000"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
loglevel = 'info'
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'

file: /var/www/mydjangosite/config/nginx.conf
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server {
        listen 80;          # Listen on IPv4
        listen [::]:80;     # Listen on IPv6
        server_name mydjangosite.com www.mydjangosite.com;
    
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/mydjangosite/config/www;
        }

         location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:9000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /code/staticfiles/;
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias /code/media/;
        }
    }
}

file: /var/www/mydjangosite/docker-compose.yml
# version: '3.8' # not required

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  static_volume: {}
  # certbot-etc: {}
  # certbot-var: {}

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./config/certbot/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf:/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf
      - ./config/certbot/conf/ssl-dhparams.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem
      # - .:/code
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - ./config/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./config/certbot/www:/var/www/mydjangosite/config/certbot/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./config/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./config/certbot/www:/var/www/allhoa/config/certbot/www
      - ./certbot-entrypoint.sh:/certbot-entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ["/certbot-entrypoint.sh"]

  web:
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      bash -c "
        cat .env &&
        pip install --default-timeout=100 --retries=5 -r requirements.txt &&
        python manage.py migrate &&
        python manage.py collectstatic --no-input &&
        gunicorn --config ./config/gunicorn.conf.py allhoa.wsgi:application"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://${DBUSER}:${DBPASSWORD}@${DBHOST}:${DBPORT}/${DBNAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

    

file: /var/www/mydjangosite/Dockerfile
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:latest

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code

# Copy the project code
COPY . /code/

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libpam-dev libedit-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --default-timeout=100 --retries=5 -r requirements.txt
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Command to run the Django application
CMD ["gunicorn", "mydjangosite.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:9000"]


What URL exactly are you calling?  It seems like your Nginx configuration isn't getting noticed, but you're mounting the config file into the right place.  (Note that the TLS-related configuration will cause problems for this initial setup: if that Nginx configuration were applied, your plain-HTTP connection should redirect to an HTTPS port that's not published out of the container, and you don't seem to have TLS certificates available that you've shown.)

Just the root domain. Ya I'm just not sure what and where I'm missing that code. Goal is to use letsencrypt like I used to do before using docker but seems to be causing issues.

In your compose file you are basically saying, 1) create two containers, one for nginx and one for django app, 2) expose 80 for nginx and expose 9000 for django, 3) create nginx right after when django is ready (depends_on). The nginx container is just sitting there without doing anything so when you visit port 80 (the default port you omitted), nginx says "I am working and now what?". You don't need a separate container for nginx and do not use runserver in production.
